# Getting the outer range of a grouped column of range types in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a column `name` consisting of text values that I want to group by. Additionally I have a table `value` consisting of numerical range values (of [range type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html)). I want to group by the `name` column and get the outer bounds for each of the groups.

Here is an example:

**Parameter table**

```
name                  value
-----                 -----
Nominal power         [1,2]
Nominal power         [2,3]
Nominal power ratio   [10,15]
Nominal power ratio   [17,19]
Hydrogen production   [1,6]
Hydrogen production   [2,9]
```

Wanted output is something like this (or lower, upper bound in separate columns):

```
name                  outer range
-----                 -----
Nominal power         [1,3]
Nominal power ratio   [10,19]
Hydrogen production   [1,9]
```

Here is a query I attempted to run, but it failed:

```
select name, upper(value), lower(value) from parameters
group by name
```

Is there a way to achieve this is Postgresql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an aggregate function, e.g.: `min(lower(value))`. From there you can create a new range:

```
select name, int4range(min(lower(value)), max(upper(value)), '[]')
from parameters
group by name;
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit to add:** I recommend that you accept the answer by @a_horse_with_no_name because it is simpler, gives the exact answer you want, and works with versions prior to PostgreSQL 14.  I would delete my answer here except that I find the `multirange` data type interesting.

Using `range_agg()` and the `range_merge()` on the new `multirange` types can do this:

```
select name, 
       range_merge(range_agg(value)) as outer_range
  from parameters
 group by name
 order by outer_range;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6500552c14026628eab0496f389b3adb)*